# A property regarding the eigenvalue of the sum of positive semidefinite matrices is positive definite?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-definite

If the sum of positive semidefinite matrices $A_i$ is positive definite (they are also symmetric), that is $$A=\sum_{i\in \mathcal{N}} A^i, \;\mathcal{N}=\{1,2,\cdots,N\}$$ is positive definite.

What's the relation between the **minimal eigenvalue** of $A$  and the **minimal positive eigenvalue** of $A^i$.

Comment: Do you mean that every sum of $A^i$ is positive defined or just this specific sum? By the way: you definition of positive definied implies also symmetric isn't it?

Comment: Thanks for your attention. Yes, they are symmetric, and sum is in the specific sum with finite individuals ($A=A^1 +A^2+\cdots+A^N$). I have improved the question, hope it's clear now.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\lambda=\inf(spectrum(A))$ and $\lambda_i=\inf(spectrum(A_i))$; then $\inf_{||x||=1}x^TAx=\lambda$ and, for every $i$, $inf_{||x||=1}x^TA_ix=\lambda_i$. Since $x^TAx=\sum_ix^TA_ix\geq \sum_i\lambda_i$, we obtain $\lambda\geq \sum_i \lambda_i$.

EDIT. The previous reasoning is valid for every symmetric matrices $A,A_i$. Moreover we may have: for every $i$, $\lambda_i=0$ and $\lambda>0$.